# Asymptotic stability of eigenvalues by compact perturbations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, stability, perturbation-theory

I need some references concerning the asymptotic stability of eigenvalues by compact perturbations. In [T. Kato, Perturbation theory for linear operators] there are some results concerning stability of the essential spectrum and of the finite number of eigenvalues. But in this book I did not find the following problem.

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let
$$
  C = A(\mathrm{Id}+B)
$$
where $A$, $B$ are two compact self-adjoint operators in $H$ with eigenvalues $a_n$, $b_n$:
$$
  |a_1| \geq |a_2| \geq \cdots \to +0, \\
  |b_1| \geq |b_2| \geq \cdots \to + 0,
$$
but, in general, with different eigenvectors. Is it possible to say that asymptotically the eigenvalues $a_n$ of $A$ and the eigenvalues $c_n$ of $C$ are the same in the sense
$$
   c_n = a_n(1+o(1)), \; n \to \infty \quad ? \tag{1}
$$
In particular, what if $A$ is a compact pseudodifferential operator and $B$ is an infinitely smoothing operator?

What are the known (more or less important cases) cases when (1) holds, except for the case when $A$, $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable?